# carriage return in Access Table

Tags: ms-access-2007, carriage-return

I have a field Large text in my Access table and When I create a Form an I add this field I can Write several lines with intro to break down each line but when I open that table in that field I only see the first line I wrote, but If I see that record by the Form I see all the lines.

Seems that the lines are stores but the table in View mode do not show them

Any idea please?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

In the table (datasheet view), increase the row height to see multiple lines per row.

Just as you would do in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Upps.

If I use the arrow down I see all the text

Sorry...